# How to make MyISAM type Relation View ini PhpMyadmin?

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

I am using phpMyAdmin Version information: 3.2.4 when I need to relation view it is not available that option, then I search problem-solving this rule must be changed from MyISAM type to InnoDB. it is not good working because just index field can in relation but another field can't to the relation.

[image: InnoDB just Relation in index field]

I want to MyISAM type can show relation view and I can to relation all field in all table at phpMyAdmin

[image: MyISAM type can to relation all field]

Comment: myISAM do NOT support foreign keys. It's not a matter of phpMyAdmin but design of database storage engine (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/myisam-storage-engine.html)

Comment: i dont need support foreign key in MyISAM but i want to myISAM can to show relation view like picture two